# Can I directly access 45-degree imagery in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

Is there a way to view the 45° imagery, which [google-maps](http://maps.google.com) provides at high-zoom levels, directly within Google-Earth?

Comment: To those voting to migrate to WebApps: Google Earth is not a web app.

Comment: Looks like it is not added to Google Earth yet http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/Xn3eWGNabS0